# their or its counterparts

Tags: grammar

> Overall, there was an increase in female fitness membership throughout the period examined, while the opposite was true for **their/its** male counterparts.

Should it be **their** or **its** here? I think since I'm comparing the memberships, **its** should be better because it's the main noun. However, **their** sounds better to my ears. I'm not sure though. Hope you all can clear this up for me.

[image]

Comment: Imho, ***its*** sounds silly. But you might consider sidestepping the issue with *...the opposite was true for **the** male counterparts*. Or don't bother with a determiner at all - *...was true for male counterparts* seems fine to me - and in fact [that's become the dominant form over recent decades.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+male+counterparts%2Cfor+male+counterparts&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: an increase in female fitness membership = a non-starter This is a find and correct question: the fitness of female members. Now, do it.

Comment: For IELTS: "Female fitness membership" should be paraphrased, merely copying the expression may suggest that you either do not understand the meaning or you are unable to say it in a different way. It could be as simple as "Overall the number of women joining fitness clubs… whereas the number of men…” Also, the number of women members in 2015 decreased by almost a third so your summary is not accurate and you will lose marks for this in a test.

Comment: @Lambie sorry but I don't understand what you meant here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did think about using the phrase "joining fitness clubs" but then I felt that female fitness membership and the number of women "joining" fitness clubs weren't the same thing. For instance, say, there are 5 people registering for fitness memberships, each of which lasts 1 year. In the next year, the memberships haven't expired, so there will still be 5 memberships recorded in that area while there are no people joining the gym that year.

Comment: I've already made another post on how to use "throughout" correctly. I'd really appreciate it if you could share your thoughts there. Here's the [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/350220/what-does-throughout-a-period-mean)

Comment: @Mari-LouA About paraphrasing, I do know that we need to paraphrase, and I did in my essay. Still, I tend to use the same phrase in the question once or twice in my essay, for I think the fact that I paraphrase it in other parts of my essay is enough to prove that my vocabulary isn't limited. Well, it is actually lol. But it's the impression I try to make. Do you think I should avoid reusing the phrase completely?

Comment: "Overall" is a general view point, it doesn't matter when someone joined or renewed their membership because the chart lists the number of members in *five year* intervals.E.g In 2015 the number of female fitness members in Thailand was lower compared to 2005 and 2010. It's OK to use the exam question phrase once as long as you don't continually use it. In your shoes I'd be tempted to use "women/men gym members" but we don't know if "fitness membership“ includes sport clubs.

Comment: I mean that the phrase: "female fitness membership" is not the best you can find. Because that would mean: fitness is a member. We'd say: The number of females with a fitness membership or the number of female members. I assume a reader will already know the membership is for a fitness establishment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be strictly correct here, it isn't just a case of choosing one pronoun or the other. The whole thing needs a rewrite.

When you compare two things, they must be comparable. You can certainly compare the results from *men* with the results from *women*. But when you use pronouns like 'their' or 'its', these always point back to something you have previously mentioned. Therefore the pronoun must be part of a comparable phrase. In other words, you ought to be able to replace whichever pronoun you choose with the entire thing it refers to and the sentence still make sense.

The problem is, you haven't mentioned any females in your text. You've used the word 'female' as an adjective to describe the noun 'membership', which you are using as an *uncountable noun* (ie you haven't used the plural 'memberships'). It is therefore incorrect when you refer to "male *counterparts*" in the plural.

You could instead say:

> Overall, there was an increase in female fitness membership throughout the period examined, while the opposite was true of male membership.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing women with men. Read the context again. You are not comparing "a membership" nor even "memberships", but the behaviour of women compared to their male counterparts.

So the pronoun should be plural: "their".

Comment: @FumbleFingers said that we could even remove the pronoun here. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is better with the determiner.

Comment: What about Tim's opinion? This is a typical case where native speakers give me different advice, so it's kinda hard to choose which way to go.

Comment: @anIELTSLearner This is a case where the grammatical and the semantic are at odds, and there's no real way to avoid infelicity when you start with "female membership". There may also be transatlantic dialect differences here, since Brits say "The company are" and  Americans say "The company is". James speaks BrE and may more readily use "their" of "female membership" than I would as I speak AmE.

Answer (score 0):

One could ask a fitness company "How large is your female membership?" Even though membership is an abstraction and doesn't have a gender, the question would be understood to mean "How many women have memberships?" or "What percentage of your membership is women?"

> There was an increase in female membership in period and a decrease in male membership.

Trying to express this with **its** or **their** *counterparts* is wrongheaded. Neither is correct.

If **membership** is the noun, it would be *counterpart* in the singular:

> There was an increase in female membership in period and a decrease in its male counterpart.

But why ask the question in such a wooden manner merely to avoid saying the word **membership** twice?

Comment: As a test taker, I don't always have enough time to come up with the best expression. So a word like "counterpart" is great for me because I can use it in a lot of different essays, hence the need to learn how to use it properly. With regard to why I feel like I should avoid saying membership twice, I think Mari-Lou A's comment above explains it.

Comment: Your suggestion to use "counterparts" does not address Mari-LouA's concern in any way.