# What does "throughout the period" mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

> *Overall, there was an increase in female fitness membership **throughout** **the period** examined, while the opposite was true for male counterparts.*

Above is a sentence I wrote that is supposed to mean "Over the period of 30 years, the number of women working out at a gym increased despite some fluctuations". In this sentence, I'm trying to ignore the changes in between and focus on the first year and the last year. I mean after everything that happened, the number increased.

My question is: Am I using "**throughout the period**" correctly here? Can it be used that way or must there be a consistent upward trend from start to finish for me to write it the way I did? If the sentence is currently incorrect, does adding **despite some fluctuations** make it right?

[image]

Comment: If you want to say that it was mostly increasing, with occasional decreases, you can say "female fitness generally increased during the period".

Comment: Could you add the [IELTS](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ielts), please? Spelled [tag:ielts]

Answer (score 3):

> Overall, there was an increase in female fitness membership **throughout the period** examined, while the opposite was true for male counterparts.

Collins Dictionary says

> If you say that something happens *throughout a particular period* of time, you mean that it happens during *the whole* of that period.

Hence we may not want to use that phrase.  Adding *despite some fluctuations* may help in minimising understanding but will lengthen the sentence.  As we just want to express a *net increase* between two points in a period of time, we may state just that:

> Overall, there was *a net increase* in female fitness membership *from 1985 to 2015*, while the opposite was true for male counterparts.

Comment: Thank you! What about "over the years"? Is it better than "throughout the years" in this case?

Comment: @anIELTSlearner They're essentially the same.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but I disagree that "... has increased over the last 30 years" means that it has increased every single year in the last 30 years, and I am confident that many native speakers would disagree with this interpretation too. Indeed, I think "... has increased over the last 30 years" is precisely what the OP is trying to express.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel you have used this word correctly in the context of what you are presenting.

The dictionary definition of 'throughout' is *in every part of a place or object*. So, saying there was an increase *throughout the period* would suggest that there was an increase at every stage of the period; in other words, that the memberships kept increasing, and increasing, and increasing. Your visual shows that isn't the case. The numbers rose, then fell, then rose, then fell.

I would say that female fitness membership *fluctuated* throughout the period.

If it had fluctuated a little, but broadly showed an increase (ie the jumps up were greater than the drops and you ended on a higher figure overall), I might say that the membership *broadly trended upwards* **over** the period. I wouldn't use 'throughout' because there was no consistency.

However, in the case of the visual you are presenting, the final number in 2015 for female membership is about a third lower than the 2 highest periods, and barely higher than the number from 25 years before it. I would not describe this as an increase.